# slick отрабатывает только после смены слайда

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

при открытии попапа у меня верстка слайдера едет
[image: верстка слайдера едет]

но при смене слайда она встает на свое место. Что за баг? как его пофиксить?[image: при смене слайда]

Comment: открыть консоль и смотреть от чего поплыло

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev колбека нет. Ошибок так же